# React Input when i try to delete uploaded file , after i delete i can not upload second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m uploading a csv file with my input `onChange` action. I can upload , but when i want to delete it and upload other file . I can not upload , even `onChange` function is not working.

```
handleFileChange(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new window.FileReader();
    this.setState({ fileName: e.target.files[0].name });
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = e => {
        const headers = e.target.result.split('\n')[0].split(',');
        this.setState({ file: e.target.result });
        this.setState({ headers });
    }
}
```

This is my input part:

```
<label htmlFor="import-csv" styleName="s.label-input">
    <i className="fa fa-upload" style={{ marginRight: '5px' }} />
            Upload
    <input id="import-csv" styleName="s.file-input" type="file" accept="text/csv" 
           onChange={e => this.handleFileChange(e)} />
</label>
```

Comment: By the way i can upload other files but i can not upload some file

Comment: Hi have you tried to reset the value of the `input[type=file]` to null?

Comment: I solved like this , i give a key to input and force to render page like this everytime i rendered key will be difference and works correctly thank you @t3